# Maven: skip test-compile in the life cycle?

Tags: testing, build, maven, compilation, skip

I have project that I set to build with the `test-jar` and normal jar by using this setting:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem with this is whenever I upgrade the project version in the pom, I need to do a build with the tests, otherwise maven won't be able to find the test-jar with the correct version during the `test-compile` phrase. A lot of time I would just want to skip the tests, but due to the test-jar missing, the `test-compile`phrase will fail.

I tried to use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, but that doesn't seem to skip the `test-compile` phase. Is there a way to skip this?

Answer (score 80):

```
$ mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true \
      -Dmaven.site.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Comment: Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code only answers.

Comment: no need of this parameter -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true - it works for me with couple of parameters to skip site staging and tests

Comment: One thing I only recently realized:  `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` and `-DskipTests=true` are NOT the same thing.

Comment: To elaborate on what Sridhar said: `skipTests` only skips execution of tests, while `maven.test.skip` skips both compilation and execution.

Comment: @FWDekker Great explanation!

Comment: Note that `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` also skips copying of test resources through the [resources:testResources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html). This may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 48):

If you want to skip the compilation of test sources, you can try configuring the [maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) suitably. This is not recommended though.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a command line param if that's possible.

Comment: @fei.  As specified in http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test, `maven.test.skip=true` skips test compilation and execution. If this is not happening, you can update your question with log.

Comment: I had set my ID to something other than `default-testCompile` and this wouldn't work correctly. Why is this specific ID required?

Comment: @Ungeheuer you're trying to override the definition of an execution that's already defined for maven-compiler-plugin.

The way I do that is `<execution><id>default-testCompile</id><phase/></execution>`, which unbinds it from any phase so it doesn't even show up as skipped. I use this in some projects to override various check-related plugins defined in parent-POMs for the default build profile.

Answer (score 18):

Little Late, But to summarise in short and be precise -

Adding to what [@Sridhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714112/sridhar-sarnobat) and [@FWDekker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307872/fwdekker) said,

`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` will just skip the Tests Execution

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip` will skip both compilation and execution of Tests.

Answer (score 5):

Just Add -Dmaven.test.skip . It will Not even compile test

Comment: Yes with this Test will not run but test files would compile . but giving only this would not compile the test files

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working command from https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html

You can skip running tests with the following command

`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

If you absolutely must, you can also use the ***maven.test.skip*** property to skip compiling the tests. ***maven.test.skip*** is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests`

Comment: This does not run tests, but still compiles them.

Comment: The second incantation helped me. I knew my tests would fail, just wanted to know whether the build (pre-fixing the tests) would be happy.