# How can I disable default lifecycle phases in Maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3

By *disable* I mean completely, entirely cut the phase from the lifecycle, so that it is not even invoked.

I might need a custom lifecycle but I could not find an easy way to define it straight in my `pom.xml`. It appears I need to *write a plugin* just to list phases I want.

For example, I would like `default-testResources`, `default-testCompile` and `default-test` phases to never happen and turn my build log from this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelpDesk Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helpdesk] in [d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\target\helpdesk]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [40 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\target\helpdesk.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

into this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelpDesk Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ helpdesk ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helpdesk] in [d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\target\helpdesk]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [40 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: d:\proj\HelpDesk\repo\target\helpdesk.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The question is why do you need such changed life cycle for what purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sort of academic interest. I don't like the idea that Maven invokes phases and plugins that I **know** have no work to do, spending computational resources and adding useless log entries. I am aware that unit tests are considered good practice by Maven, but still wonder if I could _disable_ them. Best way I found so far is ``maven.test.skip`` variable that minimized the log to what I posted. The question arose from my expectation of flexibility to adjust Maven to my project, my layout and my _build phases_. I realize it has minimal, or even unnoticeable performance impact.

Comment: @khmarbaise why can't I `maven.package.skip`? I have profile which when activated disables my verification plugin. But that's dangerous for me, and I want to prohibit the creation of a package by the JAR/shade/source/etc plugins since they would be incomplete. Basically I want to stop the build

Comment: Although I'm not sure about every lifecycle phase, it's possible to skip the _test_ lifecycle phase during the default lifecycle with 

```
-Dmaven.skip.test=true
```

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784778/maven-skip-test-compile-in-the-life-cycle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to continue using a predefined packaging (jar, war, etc.) you cannot totally remove them.  You may leave the packaging as `pom` and define your own lifecycle by binding the goals you want to the desired phases, or you may define your own lifecycle entirely.  You may also bind a default goal to phase `none` to prevent the goal from doing any real work as shown.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

All that said - khmarbaise's question is a good one.  Generally it's not a best practice to change the existing pre-built lifecycles.

Comment: With the given solution you only disable the particular plugin but not the life cycle itself.

Comment: Agreed, setting phase to `none` doesn't change the lifecycle.  If there are other plugins bound to the same lifecycle phase they will still run.  That's why I provided the other ideas as well.

Comment: Found [goals listing](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html) for bundled packaging types. The page says I need to write a plugin to define custom packaging type and a lifecycle for it. Is this the only way? Cannot I define it straight in a POM for my project with some `<lifecycle>` tag?

Comment: The `goals listing` link from @Alex is broken. I found a saved version on [the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130526015323/http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html).